# Передача двумерных массивов разной размерности (типа char) в функцию

Tags: массивы, c++

Доброго времени суток! Огромная просьба кинуть ссылку по теме или сразу код.
В общем, никак не могу разобраться, каким образом можно с помощью одной функции работать с несколькими двумерными массивами типа char.

Пример: есть 2 массива

```
char a1[13][29];  
char a2[13][14];
```

есть функция, в которую нужно передать **один из них**.

```
func(char a[][]);
```

Проблема в том, что если аргумент в функции написать вот таким образом `func(char a[][29]`);
То я могу использовать ее лишь для массива **a1**, но не для **a2**.

Каким образом мне нужно передавать массив в функцию, чтоб не важно было какой размерности он будет?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Хотите хороший совет? Если пишете на C++, избегайте нативных массивов, они неинтуитивны. С моим мнением согласен, кстати, [официальный FAQ по C++](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/arrays-are-evil.html).

Пишите так:

```
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

// ...
vector< vector<char> > a1, a2;

void func(vector< vector<char> >);
```

Всё будет работать.

---

С таким синтаксисом, как вы предлагаете, не работает, и не может в принципе. Дело в том, что процедура не знает, с каким шагом ей увеличивать адрес при переходе к новой строке.

Можно сделать некрасивую заплатку, передавая указатель на первый элемент и длину строки, и вычисляя адреса вручную:

```
(i, j) -> *(pFirst + (i * lineSize) + j)
```

Но это прошлый век, пользуйтесь стандартными контейнерами.

Comment: Ни разу не пользовался, но попробовал разобраться. Немного непонятно как мне можно его инициализировать?

Допустим объявил а1:
vector< vector<char> > a1;

И как прямо в коде сделать так, чтобы эти контейнеры были аналогом, инициализации массива вот таким образом:
char a[2][3] = {
"abc",
"def"};

Comment: @iterq: А сами пробовали? Вот [код](http://ideone.com/lQLBcW):

    vector< vector<char> > vv = { { 'a', 'b' }, { 'c', 'd' } };
    for (auto& v : vv)
    {
        for (auto& n : v)
            cout << n << " ";
        cout << endl;
    }

Comment: Да, попробовал, но и с Вашим кодом все та же ошибка:
Компилятор подчеркивает 1ю фигурную скобку(вот эту **{** { 'a', 'b' }, { 'c', 'd' } };), а при наведении выводит надпись "Initialization with {...} is not allowed for object of type...". Это меня и остановило, собственно)

Comment: @iterq: значит, у вас устаревший компилятор. g++ 4.7.2 [справляется](http://ideone.com/lQLBcW).

---
В таком случае, придётся вручную:

    vector<char> firstLine(2);
    firstLine[0] = 'a';
    firstLine[1] = 'b';

    #define ARRAYSIZE(arr) (sizeof(arr) / sizeof(arr[0]))

    char[] initializer = { 'c', 'd' };
    vector<char> secondLine(initializer, initializer + ARRZYSIZE(initializer));

    vv[0] = firstLine;
    vv[1] = secondLine;

или что-то ещё настолько же элегантное.

Comment: Все делаю в VS C++ 2010..странно, ни разу подобных проблем не было.  
В любом случае большое спасибо за информацию, думаю дальше сам разберусь.

Comment: @iterg, @VladD 

      "Компилятор подчеркивает 1ю фигурную скобку(вот эту { { 'a', 'b' }, { 'c', 'd' } };), а при наведении выводит надпись "Initialization with {...} is not allowed for object of type..."

Это не компилятор, это ide. До компилятора, как я понимаю, дело не дошло. Хотя могу и ошибаться, ms vs у меня нет.

Answer (score 0):

вот так еще можно передать

```
include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void f(char * p, int len);

int main(){
    char a[2][2] = {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd'};
    char b[3][3] = {'1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9'};

    f(&a[0][0], 4);
    cout << endl;
    f(&b[0][0], 9);

    return 0;
}

void f(char * p, int len){
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++){
        cout << *p << " ";
        p++;
    }
}
```

доступ через указатель быстрым должен быть вроде

Comment: Это покатит если не надо учитывать границы строк.